# How to show/hide menu items in side menu in app.html? Ionic 2

Tags: typescript, menu, ionic2

In my `app.component.ts` I define the pages that will go in my side menu.
And in my `app.html` I have my `<ion-menu>` with all menu items. However, there are some that are activated when the user logs on.

In my `app.component.ts` I get the user's token to know if I logged in (this is saved in the `localstorage` when the user logs in) and I save it in a variable and this I put it as conditional in my html using ngIf.

But as the user navigates through the application and clicks to logout, the side menu is not refreshed by more than removing the user's token from the localstorage.

This is my **app.component.ts**:

```
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { LoginPage } from './../pages/login/login';
import { OtherPage1 } from './../pages/others/other_one';
import { OtherPage2 } from './../pages/others/other_two';

export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild('content') menu : NavController;
  rootPage:any = HomePage;
  public userToken;
  login = LoginPage;
  home = HomePage;
  other_1 = OtherPage1;
  other_2 = OtherPage2;

  constructor(...) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });

    this.userToken = localStorage.getItem('idTokenUser');

    [...]
  }

  goPage(page:any){
    this.menu.setRoot(pagina);
    this.menuCtrl.close();
  }

  logout(){
    localStorage.removeItem('idTokenUser')
    this.menu.setRoot(HomePage);
    this.menuCtrl.close();
  }

}
```

This is my **app.html**:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" persistent="true">
    <ion-header color="primary"></ion-header>
    <ion-content>
        <ion-list>
            <button ion-item (click)="goPage(home)">
            <ion-icon item-start name="home"></ion-icon>
            Home</button>

            <button ion-item *ngIf="userToken" (click)="goPage(other_1)">
             <ion-icon item-start name="clipboard"></ion-icon>
             Other 1</button>

             <button ion-item *ngIf="userToken" (click)="goPage(other_2)">
             <ion-icon item-start name="people"></ion-icon>
             Other 2</button>

            <button ion-item *ngIf="!userToken" (click)="goPage(login)">
            <ion-icon item-start name="key"></ion-icon>
            Login</button>

            <button ion-item *ngIf="userToken" (click)="logout()">
            <ion-icon item-start name="close-circle"></ion-icon>
            Logout</button>

        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-menu>

<ion-nav [root]="hom" #content></ion-nav>
```

What is the way to remove item in side menu, when the user clicks to log out, at any time?

Comment: if you want you can always hide side menu using `$('.sidemenu').hide()` on logout click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the logout function to

```
logout(){
    localStorage.removeItem('idTokenUser');
    this.userToken = null;
    this.menu.setRoot(HomePage);
    this.menuCtrl.close();
  }
```